# Why I inject service in 2 modules is Singleton Pattern?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, service, angular-module

Below are files situation

```
AppService
AppModule
    AModule
        AComponent
    BModule
        BComponent
```

About `Service`, I know angular will generate 2 different object of service if I inject a `Service` in two components, the data of service can not to share. And the service will share data if I inject `Service` in `AppModule` named `Singleton Pattern`.

But, what if inject `Service` in `Amodule` and `BModule`? I thought the result is same as inject in component. But the fact is `Singleton Pattern`.

Why? The `Service` was injected in two different module, I suppose angular should generate 2 object of service in 2 modules. Who can help me to figue out it? Thanks.

The StackBlitz linking is [angular-service-inject-modules](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-inject-modules)

I create a demo that will output random number to check if the service is `Singleton Pattern`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you provide a service in a module and re-import it again it is available throughout the app. You can verify this by commenting out the `providers = [AppService]` from moduleB and see the same result as before.

Provide the service within  each individual component and then you can see that a new instance of the service gets injected as seen in the [working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-inject-modules-uxg8c9).

---

From the comments, if you don't want a singleton service to be injected in your app you can omit DI entirely and create a new instance of the service in each component.

```
constructor() { this.random = new AppService().random; }
```

Comment: If I don't use lazy module, and I hope the `Singleton Pattern` exist in ModuleA and ModuleB. What should I do?

Comment: Sorry did not get your question.

Comment: In my demo of stackblitz, if I inject service in ModuleA and ModuleB, the mode of service is singleton. How can I make it to be un-singleton in moduleA and ModuleB. I don't want to inject in components, because may be moduleA has a lot of components, but the components of ModuleA should share data of service.

Comment: One option is to inject the service at the component level which is the preferred way. But since you don't want to use it like that you can create a new instance manually in the constructor in both components i.e `constructor() {
    this.random = new AppService().random;
  }`